# Is there a gun similar to The Deliverer?

Tags: fallout-4

I failed "Tradecraft" a while back and found out about the gun after the fact.

Are there any aesthetically similar (silenced) pistols?

Comment: Added a note to the answer to make clear that those other options are not as good as the Deliverer. If you can go back, it might be worth it to get the Deliverer.

Comment: @DCShannon Thank you. I've progressed a significant amount between the time of finding The Railroad and now. So, I'm in a real bind at this point....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can suppress **10mm pistols**, **pipe pistols**, and **bolt-action pistols**.

You can also suppress the rifle versions of these weapons, of course. In addition, the combat rifle and the hunting rifle can also be suppressed.

The suppressor is a muzzle mod.

Creating such a suppressor will require that you level up Gun Nut. I think the exact level required varies between weapons, but I don't see that information on Nukapedia at the moment.

Alternatively, you could remove the mod from another weapon and move it to the one you're using. It may be worth purchasing a suppressed version of one of these weapons just to get the mod, if you don't have enough ranks in Gun Nut.

These guns allow you to attach a wider variety of mods to them compared to the Deliverer, including better optics. Despite this, the Deliverer is a better weapon for most situations with most characters. As noted on [Nukapedia's Deliverer page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Deliverer),

> While it uses the same ammunition as the 10mm, the Deliverer outperforms comparably modified 10mm pistols in almost every area.

Comment: However, there are mods you can put on a 10mm that you can't put on _The Deliverer_ - like reflex sights and scopes.

Comment: @T.J.L. That's a good point. Added it to the answer.

Comment: @DCShannon, doh, dunno how I missed that, sorry!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but I can't promise if it's called Officer's Pistol. I found it in the vault 111  overseer's office, but I only ever found it once.

[image: gun as found]

Comment: "I can't promise it", what does that mean?

Comment: There will be a 10mm pistol on the overseer's desk in vault 111. Note that there are known mods that muck with its placement (some removing it entirely.)